# Hacer un nav para desktop y otro para mobile html

Tags: html, css, programación-móvil, nav, flex

Estoy tratando de adaptar mi nav a mobile y se me es imposible. Quiero saber si se puede hacer lo siguiente(si es una buena practica o esta feo):

Hacer un nav que se muestre únicamente para desktop y otro nav y que tenga display none y que cuando la pantalla tenga 1000px x ejemplo se muestre y el de desktop se oculte, por lo que tendría 2 navs en mi html. Lo que quiero lograr es masomenos el nav mobile que tiene adidas.
Espero que se haya entendido.

Estoy trabajando con HTML, CSS y JS.

Comment: Y ¿por qué no solo un nav y mediante media queries modificas su apariencia según donde sea visualizado?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un [mcve] de lo que tengas hasta ahora? ¿Utilizas algún framework para CSS (como Bootstrap por ejemplo)?